# how to embed flash/SWF animation in startup screen in IOS app?

Tags: ios, animation, flash

i wanna to embed an animated logo in the application startup screen, this logo is already done in 2 formats of files SWF and Flash, my question is about how to embed these files directly in the application startup screen, such that the animated logo appears directly on the startup screen.

Appreciate your concern,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. iOS does not support Flash.

Update: to follow up with a possible solution, since your Flash is just an animation, perhaps you can just render it to a video and use that instead?

Answer (score 0):

First off, your start-up screen is a static image ("`Default.png`")... so you can't do animated stuff there.

Once your app fully starts up and the static image disappears, then you could have something animated.

In a practical sense, it can *not* be Flash or a SWF though (Flash files are SWF files, by the way).  One can build Flash-based apps for iOS using [Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air.html), but that's a full blown environment and IDE separate from Xcode.

It'd be smarter to do your start-up animation using CoreAnimation, HTML5 or some other fine animating framework (Unity, Cocos2d or whatever).

Or a separate video file (in which case the user has minimal interaction possibilities).  But +1 to Darren for suggesting this answer faster than I could think of it.

Comment: thanks for the responses i got some useful ideas about working with webviews with a HTML5 code that could embed a video (flash/...) file into it and running it automatically without player controls.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to publish your app on the AppStore, then what you are trying to do is Impossible !

Your best option is to create the animation you want using Core animation or you can simply convert that animation to a video and play it once your app is loaded.